# Given $ab+bc+ca=3abc$, prove $\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c(a^2+b^2 )}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a(b^2+c^2)}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{b(c^2+a^2 )}}\leq 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

$a, b, c$ are positive real numbers such that    $ab+bc+ca=3abc$

Prove∶
$$\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c(a^2+b^2 )}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a(b^2+c^2)}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{b(c^2+a^2 )}}\;\;\leq\; 3$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to prove that $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c(a^2+b^2)}}\leq\frac{ab+ac+bc}{abc}$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab(a+b)}{a^2+b^2}}\leq\frac{ab+ac+bc}{\sqrt{abc}}$$
By C-S $\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab(a+b)}{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2\leq(ab+ac+bc)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{a^2+b^2}$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{a^2+b^2}\leq\frac{ab+ac+bc}{abc}$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{a^2+b^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)$,

which is just $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a-b)^2}{2ab(a^2+b^2)}\geq0$.

Done!

Comment: Very nice SOS +1

Comment: Thanks,  can we solve this other way or explain oneby one?.not breifly.Because cyc sum is not undersantable.

Comment: @Afet A cyclic sum it's $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a-b)^2}{2ab(a^2+b^2)}=\frac{(a+b)(a-b)^2}{2ab(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{(b+c)(b-c)^2}{2bc(b^2+c^2)}+\frac{(c+a)(c-a)^2}{2ca(a^2+c^2)}$ and it's obvious that it's non-negative.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg. Thanks. Now everything is clear.